# Empirical spectral distribution, sample covariance of normal distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, random-matrices

Assume I have i.i.d samples $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$, $1\leq i\leq n$, with an arbitrary positive definite covariance matrix $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$.

What does the spectral distribution of the sample covariance $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}X_iX_i^T$ look like?

The literature on the topic seems to be too progressed for me to find an answer to this sample question. I've found papers that allow way too general dependence structures but don't even talk about simple cases like mine, and I've found lecture notes or short-proof-of papers that discuss the $\Sigma=I$ (Marchenko--Pastur) case at lengths, but not the in between case I'm in interested in. The original theorem would be the special case where the spectral distribution of $\Sigma$ is a Dirac measure at each dimension.

Reminder: the empirical spectral distribution of a matrix is the sum of dirac measures in the eigenvalues, i.e. it is a discrete measure on the positive half line. If $\Sigma=I_d$ the spectral distribution of the sample covariance matrix (a *random* measure) converges almost surely to a continuous Marchenko--Pastur distribution with one free parameter, $\lambda=d/n$, as $d,n\to\infty$.
I'm aware that in my case, I'll have to specify what it means for $d$ to change, if I talk about $\Sigma$ fixed. I'd be happy for an answer that assumes the spectral distribution of $\Sigma$ converge to a fixed spectral distribution as the dimension grows.

EDIT: To avoid the X-Y problem: what I really want is to be able to decide, by looking at a sample covariance matrix with $n\ll d$, whether the full covariance $\Sigma$ has a dominant eigenvalue or not, i.e., whether $\lambda_d/\sum_{0<i<d}\lambda_i$ is large.

Comment: I realized the original paper does discuss the anisotropic case. Answers are still welcome but i reckon there is a chance i can figure it out myself if I understood this right

Comment: After some more looking into the literature, this seems to be an open research question. The general Marchenko-Pastur equation does provide the asymptotic empirical spectral distribution in the anisotropic case in form of a difficult to analyze and even more difficult to numerically compute equation for its Stieltjes transform, but deriving consistent estimators for individual eigenvalues seems very difficult.

Comment: Hello, can you provide a reference to the paper you are mentioning?